# How do I send values multiple times to a firebase realtime database with a single button click using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to send values multiple times to a firebase database. The user enters values from an html form,say 'school_name', 'centre number'.These values are to be sent to a firebase database.For the first time, a set of the above stated values is sent with 'mathematics' as a 'subject' and '0' as the 'percentage-passrate'. For the second time, another set of the above stated values is sent but now the 'subject' should change to 'science' and the 'percentage-passrate' should be 'zero' again. I am trying to avoid sending "subject-names" as "keys", i want to send them as "values" for the 'subject' "key".

I am using a for loop and my code is not executing, here is a piece of it:

```js
var subjects = ['Mathematics', 'Science','Geography','Sociology','History','Commerce'];

var school_name;
var center_number;

function sendSchool(){

  school_name= document.getElementById("school_name").value;
  center_number= document.getElementById("center_number").value;

  for (i=0; i<subjects.length; i++){
    firebase.database().ref("schools_subjects").push().set({
      "school_name":school_name,
      "center_number":center_number,
      "subject":subjects[i],
      "passrate":0
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: At a first glance the code you shared looks fine. But "my code is not executing" is really hard to help with. If you set a breakpoint on `school_name` and run in a debugger, does it ever get to that line? If you then step through the code, does it get to `firebase.database().ref("schools_subjects").push().set({`? Do all lines and variables look good?

Comment: What I meant by "my code is not executing" is that no values were appearing on the firebase database. However, I suspect that it was a poor network connection because when I opened the database today, the values were appearing. It seems like they had been sent but they were not appearing. Thanks a lot Mr Frank for your willingness to help

Comment: Good to hear that it works now. 